# JavaScript works when tested locally, but not when accessed on server

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a simple interest calculator as practice before my web dev class, and hosting it on a raspberry pi from home. Whenever I was testing the JS locally on my machine it was working as intended, however once I uploaded it, the JS doesn't work any longer.

The Sources window in Chrome helped me discover that the monthsFlag and yearsFlag were left undefined, therefore breaking my function. This doesn't happen when I test the file locally on my machine.

```js
            var dollarFlag =false;
            var poundFlag =false;
            var euroFlag =false;
            var yearsFlag =true;
             var monthsFlag =false;

            function currencyCheck() {
                
                if(document.getElementById("currency-select").value == 'dollar'){dollarFlag = true};
                if(document.getElementById("currency-select").value == 'pound'){poundFlag = true};
                if(document.getElementById("currency-select").value == 'euro'){euroFlag = true};
            }
            function timeCheck() {
                
                if(document.getElementById("period-select").value == 'months'){
                    monthsFlag = true;
                    yearsFlag = false;
                    };
            }
            function calculate(){
                var principal = document.getElementById("principal").value;
                var rate = document.getElementById("rate").value;
                var period = document.getElementById("period").value;

                rate = (rate*0.01)/12;

                if(yearsFlag){
                    var months = period*12;
                    var interest = principal*rate*months;
                    var total = (parseFloat(principal)+parseFloat(interest));

                    document.getElementById("interest-total").value = interest;
                    document.getElementById("total").value = (total);
                }
                else if(monthsFlag){
                    var interest = principal*rate*period;
                    var total = (parseFloat(principal)+parseFloat(interest));

                    document.getElementById("interest-total").value = interest;
                    document.getElementById("total").value = (total);
                    
                    var yearsFlag =true;
                    var monthsFlag =false;
                    
                }
                
            }
```

```html
<div class="calc-section-wrap" id="div-one">
                    <label for="currency-select">Select currency:</label>
                    <select name="currency-select" id="currency-select" onchange="currencyCheck()">
                        <option value="dollar">Dollar</option>
                        <option value="pound">Pound</option>
                        <option value="euro">Euro</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="calc-section-wrap" id="div-two">
                    <label for="principal">Principal Amount:</label>
                    <input id="principal" name="principal" type="number">
                </div>
                <div class="calc-section-wrap" id="div-three">
                    <label for="rate">Annual Interest rate(Percent):</label>
                    <input id="rate" name="rate" type="number">
                </div>
                <div class="calc-section-wrap" id="div-four">
                    <label for="period">Period:</label>
                    <input id="period" name="period" type="number">
                    <select name="period-select" id="period-select" onchange="timeCheck()">
                        <option value="years">Years</option>
                        <option value="months">Months</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="calc-section-wrap" id="div-btn">
                    <button type="button" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
                    <button type="reset">Clear</button>
                </div>
                <div class="calc-section-wrap" id="div-total">
                    <label for="interest-total">Interest Amount:</label>
                    <input id="interest-total" name="interest-total" type="number"><br/>
                    <label for="total">Total Amount:</label>
                    <input id="total" name="total" type="number">
                </div>
```

The desired behavior is to retrieve the values from the form, including the principal, interest rate and period of loan, and save them in the appropriate variables(principal,rate, and period). Then perform the calculation and display the outcome in the input elements named "interest-total" and total".

Also I am aware that there is probably a lot of problems with both my HTML and JS, and that this is not in any way an elegant solution. I welcome any feedback on how to improve it! I'm still getting my footing in the web dev stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be the related to the last 2 lines where you recreate the variables (or similar. look for other places.) you defined the vars at the top, then did it again at the bottom.

```
var yearsFlag =true;
var monthsFlag =false;
```

You don't need the `var` the second time.

Just a quick thought.

Comment: I see now that this happens a few times with other variables too. Set your vars once, at the top of the JS, and/or the top of functions.

Comment: Aaahh....I did not even realize that I did that! I am sure those are local variables that are overriding the global ones outside of the function. Thank you!

Comment: I just tested it and this fixed it.